# How to debug an MS Word add-in?

Tags: debugging, ms-word

How to debug an MS Word add-in?

I tried to add an MS Word add-on in a blank Word document. When I open the VBA editor I am not able to open/expand the project as it says "Project is unviewable".

What I need is to place a breakpoint on the code and run the add-on to debug the add-on after stopping at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your MS Word document file (.docx).
2. Add or enable the add-in to the document using the "Developer" tab.
3. The add-in file has the extension ".dotm". Use "File" menu to open the add-in file.
4. Open VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) editor.
5. Put a breakpoint in the code.
6. Now go to the MS Word document file (.docx) and run the add-in. This should stop the code at the breakpoint for debugging.